# How to increase version variable of python file via Vim?

Tags: python, vim, version-control, version, versioning

I used `__version__` variable for different files within my module. For example,

`""" foo.py """
__version__ = '0.0.1'`

`""" bar.py """
__version__ = '1.0.1.111'`

I am looking for any Vim command/plugin to automatically increase the version number string. E.g, press **F12**,

```
'0.0.1' => '0.0.2'
'1.0.1.111' => '1.0.1.112'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should actually work:

```
:g/^__version__/exe "normal! $b\<C-A>"
```

What it does is the following:

it executes `$\<C-A>` on every line where `__version__` is found.
`$` goes to the last character on the line (minor version), and `<C-A>` increments the number under the cursor, as nbari said.

That can be modified for the first part of the version number it is:

```
:g/^__version__/exe "normal! \<C-A>"
```

And so on.

Comment: Thanks for the command. I made little change `:g/^__version__/exe "normal! $b\<C-A>"`. `^` to avoid matching other lines. `b` to go back as last char is quotation mark.

Comment: sure, forgotten the quote sorry, i've updated my answer

Comment: nice, I also create shortcut in my .vimrc `noremap <F12> <ESC>:g/^__version__/exe "normal! $b\<C-A>"<CR>`.

Answer (score 1):

In vim by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> in normal mode will increase the number + 1 under the cursor and  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> will decrese it.

So in this case:

```
""" foo.py """ 
__version__ = '0.0.1'
```

by putting the cursor in 1 and pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> will increment the value to 2:

```
__version__ = '0.0.2'
```

This works if you just want to bump the patch [semver](http://semver.org) version, but to bump to a major, minor probably a plugin.

Something like this probably could be adapted https://github.com/nbari/semverbump in this case the script bumps the version based on the git tag.